# How to mock application context

Tags: java, android, unit-testing, mockito

How do we mock an Application Context? I got a presenter which I intend to write a test for. The parameters it receives were a `view` and `Context`. How do I create a mock for context to work?

```
public TutorProfilePresenter(TutorProfileScreenView view, Context context){
     this.view = view;
     this.context = context
}
            
public void setPrice(float price,int selectedTopics){
      int topicsPrice = 0;
      if(selectedTopics>2)
      {
        topicsPrice = (int) ((price/5.0)*(selectedTopics-2));
      }
                    
                    
      view.setBasePrice(price,topicsPrice,selectedTopics,
                        price+topicsPrice);
}
```

Comment: add the impl you want to test and lets see

Comment: i have updated my question. please check it

Comment: I just wanted to write a sample snippet to test whether the method in view(which is a interface) from presenter is being called to update activity content.

Answer (score 8):

As a base I would use the Mockito annotations( i assume you want to mock the view also):

```
public class TutorProfilePresenter{

   @InjectMocks
   private TutorProfilePresenter presenter;

   @Mock
   private TutorProfileScreenView viewMock;
   @Mock
   private Context contextMock;

   @Before
   public void init(){
       MockitoAnnotations.initMocks(this);
   }

   @Test
   public void test() throws Exception{
      // configure mocks
      when(contextMock.someMethod()).thenReturn(someValue);

      // call method on presenter

      // verify
      verify(viewMock).setBasePrice(someNumber...)
   }

}
```

This would inject ready to configure mocks into your class under test.

More insight on Mockito stubbing: [sourceartists.com/mockito-stubbing](https://www.sourceartists.com/blog/unit-testing/mockito-stubbing/20)

Comment: How do we ensure that the activity is being called through view from presenter? How do i write test to check it?

Comment: you use verify as in the example